# Strange CSS bug in Meteor app which doesn't let the styles render properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, meteor

In my Meteor 1.6.0.4 app, css styles don't render properly as they render with static HTML files. The strange thing is that when I make any change in the CSS file while the app is running on development server, then the CSS is hot reloaded again and the styles render properly, but a browser refresh makes the CSS styles bad again.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like an order dependency in your CSS loading. Are you using eager loading of CSS files, or manual?

Comment: do you use [meteor css modules](https://github.com/nathantreid/meteor-css-modules) package? i've encountered the same issue on development but working properly on production

Comment: @Mikkel I don't think it's eager loading, Meteor compiles all the CSS into one big files and links it to the main app.

Comment: @ishadif No I am not using **meteor css modules**, I just pasted all the CSS styles given by the designer into a single CSS file.

Comment: It might still be an order dependency... Try setting !important on it to see if that makes a difference